# Метка [javascript] и фреймворки

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Хочу узнать мнение. Есть вопрос [Конфликт datepicker и fancybox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466775)
У этого вопроса изначально была метка [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). Я посмотрел на суть вопроса и подумалось мне что этот вопрос слишком про библиотеки для JavaScript, ни никак не про сам JavaScript и удалил метку. Теперь вот в сомнении, правильно-ли я поступил.

С одной стороны и правда вопрос про конфликты между двумя сторонними модулями (по вине ТС, но все-таки) и если бы это бы другой язык, витуация не поменялась бы.

С другой стороны, как ни крути, а это библиотеки, написанные на Javascript и метка наверное нужна.

Подскажите какие-нибудь аргументы за и против этих подходов.

Comment: Если вы удалите метку [tag:javascript], то как знатоки javascript найдут этот вопрос? Библиотечные метки должны дополнять языковые, а не заменять.

Comment: Понял. Пойду, добавлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метка по языку программирования должна стоять вместе с меткой по фреймвёку, если только ты не стопроцентно уверен, что речь о какой-то фишке данного фреймвёрка и метка по языку не принесёт дополнительной пользы. И лучше чтобы в этом был так же уверен ещё и автор вопроса, а не только ты. Ну либо после ответа так сделать.

Comment: Ну вот в приведенном вопросе я сначала подумал, что JS тут не при чем, потом засомневался, поэтому спросил совета. Спасибо за гирьку на одну из чаш :)